# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 INSTANCESHAREWOWDIR Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL SERVER R2 Express Advanced Services on my VServer (Windows 2008 SP2 64bit). The server has also a sql server 2005 express instance for plesk...

I am running in the strange Setup issue where the installation dir could not be set.

I found tons of articles about this issue like this

http://www.cannontrodder.net/2009/07/24/sql-server-2008-x64-on-windows-server-2008-x64-is-utterly-broken/

I did follow the steps but without any luck it seems like I can't change the path and following command does not effect anything...

running this command does not change the path ...

```
    setup /action=install /INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\" 
/INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Shared\\"
```

I am out of ideas... any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise on a Windows 2003 Server (64 bit), with the same WOWDIR problem as you've described.

But from your post, I followed the link to the CannonTrodder website and it has solved my problem and has allowed me to proceed past that point in the installation.

Bearing in mind you posted this in August, are you still experiencing the same problem now?